# How to replace value in array in mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

How to replace value in array in mongo?

```
const { email, tablesState } = req.body
            Users.update({ email }, { $set: tablesState }
                , function (err, WriteResult) {
                    if (err) return handleError(err);
                    res.status(201).json(WriteResult)
                }
            )
```

mongoDB Collection
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYHF0.png)

I need to replace "TablesState" but a new element of the array is created and the old one remains.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the update command should be something like this:

```
Users.update({"email" : "test@test.ru"},
             {$set: { "email" : "newEmail"}});
```

More information [here](https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-update-document.html).

Happy coding.